# Replace specific instance of period in python string

Tags: python, regex

Lets say I have a string like

```
s=""" Bob sent some money to Ana. It was 10.23 dollars. Ana thanked him. 

"""
```

I want the output to be

```
Bob sent some money to Ana. It was dollars. Ana thanked him.
```

So basically only keep alphabets and period which marks the end of sentence. Remove non alphabet character and also periods in between numbers.

I am trying to use

```
re.sub(r"[^A-za-z.\n]"," ",s)
```

But this obviously will keep the period in between the no. and gives

```
' Bob sent some money to Ana. It was   .   dollars. Ana thanked him. \n\n'
```

I want to remove the period in between the numbers too as later I want to break a text string into sentences and that would look for periods or \n as end of a sentence. Having a period which was part of a decimal number will break the sentence using that period too and that is not ideal

Comment: First make a regex to find floats, then a regex for integers

Comment: `Remove non alphabet character` ... can you give us examples of other dots you want to remove?

Comment: I think this dot is good. Basically i want to keep sentences and words with no other special character, dots or numbers. The dot which signifies the end of a sentence should only be there.

Comment: @abarnert no that doesn't work. It is basically same as the previous one. You are just saying remove 1 or more of things which are not part of the bracket

Comment: You may want to look for [`\d+(?:\.+\d+)*\s*|[^a-zA-Z.\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/HCLipi/1)

Comment: Also, do you actually want extra spaces in the result string? Because if not, you don't want to replace substrings that don't include a space with a space.

Comment: @revo Yours seemed to have worked. I shortened it to 

\d+.+\d+|[^a-zA-Z.] and this seems to work too. Any reason why to include the group as you showed?

Comment: The one you cooked matches wrong substring like in `This is 2 good words out of 5`

Comment: @abarnert yours removes all periods.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and also periods in between numbers.

A period in between numbers means it precedes at least one digit. So you could match these decimal points with `\.+(?=\d)`. `+` quantifier is not a must but can match edge cases like `1.......2` as well:

```
re.sub(r"\.+(?=\d)|[^a-z\s.]", "", s, 0, re.IGNORECASE);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThMAqW/2)

You may also want to remove extra leading spaces. If so then consider them in your regex:

```
\s*(?:\d+\.+(?=\d)|[^a-z\s.])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThMAqW/1)

Comment: I didn't want to add this in answer but second solution could be shorten to `\.+(?=\d)|\s*[^a-z\s.]` with a little difference in matching. E.g `.2`